# Add code around one particular result from SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code SELECTING the Title and Image from the "Courses" table in my database.

```
<?php
    $username = 'REMOVED';
    $password = 'REMOVED';

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=REMOVED', $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Title, Image FROM Courses');
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            print_r($row);
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

How can I make it so that the Title has a header tag wrapped around it and the Image is inside of an image src=""?

Answer (score 0):

depending on your PDO settings the result may for example be returned in an associative array (which would be the most common default setting):

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<img src="' . $row["Image"] . '" title="' . $row["Title"] . '">';
}
```

**update:** to force the fetching of associative array, just replace `$stmt->fetch()` with `$stmt->fetch((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 0):

replace while loop with following code:

```
$string="<header>";
$imagesrc="";

While($row=$stmt->fetch()){
  $string+=$row['Title'];
  $imagesrc=$row['Image'];
}

$string+="</header>";
$stringImage="<img src='".$imagesrc."' />";
```